# Will all widgets, children of IndexedStack, initial simultaneously?

Tags: flutter

I am using IndexedStack for BottomNavigationBar to prevent pages initial every time I change tab.
However, it seems that there is another problem about pages initailization. I find all pages will initial at the time. Is that true?
If so, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I have already solved this problem. Just using `PageView` instead of `IndexedStack`. If you don't wanna rebuild page every time you tab into. Let pages' state with `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`, and IDE will make you know what to do to work.